# why does "perturbation" mean small change while "perturb" means greatly disturb?

Tags: etymology

I only recently looked into the etymology of the word "disturb", which means "per-turb", completely (through, thoroughly) + disturb, which translated into "disturb **greatly** in mind".

My question is that how did the word "pertubation" get the meaning of "small changes" as in "perturbation in Jupiter's orbital" and "perturbation theory" in physics?

Comment: It seems, that the meaning conveyed by the prefix "per-" was been dropped for both senses of the word you list: [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perturb) *With its per- prefix, perturb meant originally "thoroughly upset", though today the word has lost most of its intense edge. Perturb and perturbation are often used by scientists, usually when speaking of a change in their data indicating that something has affected some normal process.*

Comment: "Perturb" has a scientific meaning and an everyday meaning, as any good dictionary will show (e.g. Merriam-Webster); this isn't uncommon in English. The same is true of "perturbation" (looking at usage examples in a dictionary will make this clearer than the definition alone). A good etymological dictionary will trace the changing meaning of both words.

Comment: @Stuart F Thanks! Could you recommand a good etymology dictionary where the changes of these two words were traced? I could not find such dictionaires and I am hoping that you could point some directions!

Comment: @katatahito Interesting point! My guess is that words in academia use tend to "loose edge", as in "permutation" in math is less than "completely change", but I could not find more examples to testify it. If the meaning of perturbation is already weakened in 14.C. then probably that's how the word purtabation picked up the meaning of "small change".

Comment: Although the previously mentioned notation from Merriam-Webster indicates etymological origins, neither [perturbation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perturbation) nor [perturb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perturb) have current definitions (at least at M-W) that indicate either small or great change; in fact, the quantity of change is not assumed in any way. What is your source for thinking that either word *does* have such a current meaning, in any context?

Comment: @JasonBassford see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/perturb). I have to mention that I am not a native speaker and I looked up in Longman and oxford's online dictionary and there is indeed no mention of "greatly" disturb. However in Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary 11th the explannation was "1: to disturb greatly in mind". In Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner's Dictionary it says "1.VERB If something perturbs you, it worries you quite a lot.". But now I tend to believe that this word has lost its edge.

Answer (score 1):

When you consider that Jupiter is the largest planet in the Solar System (more than 1,300 Earths could fit inside it; *all* the other planets could fit inside it), anything that can cause at-*all*-detectable changes in Jupiter's orbit is by definition not a *small* disturbance: "perturbance" fits.

Comment: Sorry @Raven I do not agree with you. A purturbation is to consider the effects of two interactions **relatively**. Thus the pertubation, however big it is independently, is small compared to the interaction between the sun and the Jupiter, which is why the perturbation theory works at all.